# Clickable Image Map with Show/Hide div functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagemap

I have built an image map of Ireland which will list suppliers by county, but I want each county to display only when it's clicked on. I tried to use the jQuery suggested [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009532/how-can-i-use-an-image-map-to-show-hide-a-particular-div)

```
$('[item]').click(function(){
var item=$(this).attr('item');
$(".display").hide();
$("#"+item).show();
return false;
});
```

but it's not working with the first two counties on my map e.g.

```
<IMG SRC="http://i61.tinypic.com/25su2q9.gif" USEMAP="#irelandmap" BORDER=0>
<MAP NAME="irelandmap">
<AREA SHAPE=POLY COORDS="148,103,165,94,170,94,179,87,170,80,169,74,173,74,179,73,188,67,192,60,195,51,195,44,201,38,210,30,221,21,218,18,213,13,208,8,208,14,206,17,202,17,196,17,190,17,197,33,197,34,191,46,185,52,179,49,183,40,187,29,183,23,180,39,176,36,175,30,174,25,172,33,167,32,166,28,162,25,153,32,146,30,144,37,138,46,138,53,141,60,144,62,140,63,131,64,137,70,133,74,121,72,118,81,127,85,134,86,140,85,146,81,156,81,160,85,157,91,148,93,147,101" href="#"  alt="donegal" item="donegal" OnMouseOut="window.status=''; return true"  TITLE="Donegal">
<AREA SHAPE=POLY COORDS="197,52,197,43,200,38,205,35,211,37,219,37,224,30,224,24,232,24,240,23,244,26,256,73,251,79,244,81,233,73,227,69,228,61,218,60,199,47" href="#" alt="Derry" item="derry" OnMouseOut="window.status=''; return true"  TITLE="Derry">
```

...

```
<strong>ULSTER</strong>

<div id="derry" class="display">Derry
Test</div>
```

With this CSS as a test:

```
.display {
background-color: red;
color: white;
padding: 5px;
text-align:center;
display:none;
}
```

What am I doing wrong that this is not working the same way as the [original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtKXL/6/)?

[My fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/CgF7k/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't include `jQuery library`!
See [UPDATED DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/CgF7k/1/)